# One to many hibernate xml mapping with composite key generating update statements instead of insert

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am currently working on a one to many hibernate xml mapping.I want to insert records into two tables(MERCHANT_INFO, MERCHANT_SERVICE). not update the entries.  eventhough I'm using save as below in daoImpl class,

```
 getHibernateTemplate().save(objMerchantInfoEntity);
```

Hibernate is generating few update statements as below

```
 Hibernate: insert into MERCHANT_INFO (MID,...) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 Hibernate: update MERCHANT_SERVICE set TXN_MIN=?, TXN_MAX=?, POS_ID=?, STATUS=?, UPDATED_BY=? where SERVICE_CODE=? and MID=?
 Hibernate: update MERCHANT_SERVICE set TXN_MIN=?, TXN_MAX=?, POS_ID=?, STATUS=?, UPDATED_BY=? where SERVICE_CODE=? and MID=?
```

May i know why last two statements are coming as update instead of insert?

ONE side -> MERCHANT_INFO table primary key: MID
Many Side -> MERCHANT SERVICE table composite key: MID,SERVICE_CODE (MID is forign key from MERCHANT_INFO table)

in MerchantInfo.hbm.xml..

```
<set
    name="merchantServices" 
    lazy="true"
    inverse="true"
    cascade="save-update"
>
    <key>
        <column name="MID" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many
        class="com.en.common.entity.MerchantServiceEntity"
    />
</set>
```

In MerchantService.hbm.xml..

```
<composite-id name="comp_id" class="com.en.common.entity.MerchantServicePK">
        <key-property
            name="serviceCode"
            column="SERVICE_CODE"
            type="java.lang.String"
            length="32"
        />
        <key-property
            name="merchantId"
            column="MID"
            type="java.lang.Long"
            length="38"
        />
    </composite-id>
...
<!-- bi-directional many-to-one association to MerchantInfo -->
    <many-to-one
        name="MerchantInfoEntity"
        class="com.en.common.entity.MerchantInfoEntity"
        update="false"
        insert="false"

    >
         <column name="MID" />
    </many-to-one>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using MerchantServiceEntity Reference on MerchantInfo class. As far as i know, when you try to save a detached entity, hibernate doesn't know if there is any changes or not in  MerchantServiceEntity reference variable since it is not in managed state. So, instead he tries to update the properties in this case.

Comment: I suspect the issue here is composite key. one of the key(MID) is foreign key which would updated from the parent table(sequence), the other key (SERVICE_CODE) need to be assigned manually. So when i'm assigning that key, hibernate is considering it as  key available and generating the update statement.